# How to apply an image to a QPushButton in QT Creator

Tags: c++, image, qt, resources

I can't manage to view any picture on Qobjects, like a QPushButton, using the setIcon() function.
This probably has to do with the image url being erroneously specified, inside the QPixMap pix("url") function. This is what I've got:

```
QPixmap pix(":/Resources/flag.png");
QIcon icon(pix);

button->setIcon(icon);
```

I have a flag.png file inside the directory "Other files/Resources/flag.png".

I really don't know how resources should be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Qt Resource file (`File > New > Qt > Resource File`).  Then add a prefix into the resource file, then add a file to the resource file.

After all of that is done, right click on the listing for that file and select `Copy resource path`.  Then paste that path into your cpp file, and surround it in quotes.

Hope that helps.